# laravel livewire upload image error validation

Tags: php

i have the same problem in this issue:

[Laravel Livewire File Upload Not Validating and is returning a Livewire\TemporaryUploadedFile instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71594254/laravel-livewire-file-upload-not-validating-and-is-returning-a-livewire-temporar)

i want upload my image path in database product, but i have some error
first in validate file image, missing field image or image required
same error in edit edit view,
but if i push second time the button il all ok and work

this is my controller:

```
 public function store()
    {
       $data= $this->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
          //  'detail' => 'required',
            //'giac' => 'required',
            'classe' => 'required',
            'photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png,svg,gif|max:2024', // 1MB Max
        ]);
      //  $this->photo->store('documents');
        $data['photo']= $this->photo->store('documents');
      $filename = $this->photo->store('documents','public');
        $data['photo'] = $filename;
        $this->photo = $filename;

        Product::updateOrCreate(['id' => $this->product_id], [
            'name' => $this->name,
           // 'detail' => $this->detail,
            'giac'  =>$this->giac,
             'photo' =>$this->photo
        ]);
            //$this->reset();
        session()->flash('message',
            $this->product_id ? 'Product Updated Successfully.' : 'Product Created Successfully.');

        $this->closeModal();
        $this->resetInputFields();
    }
```

this is my blade file:

```
<div class="fixed z-10 inset-0 overflow-y-auto ease-out duration-400">
   <div class="flex items-end justify-center min-h-screen pt-4 px-4 pb-20 text-center sm:block sm:p-0">

     <div class="fixed inset-0 transition-opacity">
       <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-500 opacity-75"></div>
     </div>

     <!-- This element is to trick the browser into centering the modal contents. -->
     <span class="hidden sm:inline-block sm:align-middle sm:h-screen"></span>?

     <div class="inline-block align-bottom bg-white rounded-lg text-left overflow-hidden shadow-xl transform transition-all sm:my-8 sm:align-middle sm:max-w-lg sm:w-full" role="dialog" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-headline">
       <form>
       <div class="bg-white px-4 pt-5 pb-4 sm:p-6 sm:pb-4">
         <div class="">
                 <div class="mb-4">
                     <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Codice:</label>
                     <input type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Enter Name" wire:model="minsan">
                     @error('minsan') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
                 </div>
             <div class="mb-4">
                 <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Giacenza:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Enter Name" wire:model="giac">
                 @error('giac') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
             </div>
               <div class="mb-4">
                   <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Descrizione:</label>
                   <input type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Enter Name" wire:model="name">
                   @error('name') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
               </div>
             <div class="mb-4">
                 <label for="exampleFormControlInput1" class="block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2">Classe:</label>
                 <input type="text" class="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline" id="exampleFormControlInput1" placeholder="Enter Name" wire:model="classe">
                 @error('classe') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span>@enderror
             </div>

             <form wire:submit.prevent="uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                 <input type="file" wire:model="photo">

                 @error('photo') <span class="text-red-500">{{ $message }}</span> @enderror


             </form>
         </div>
       </div>

       <div class="bg-gray-50 px-4 py-3 sm:px-6 sm:flex sm:flex-row-reverse">
         <span class="flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:ml-3 sm:w-auto">
           <button wire:click.prevent="store()" type="button" class="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-transparent px-4 py-2 bg-green-600 text-base leading-6 font-medium text-white shadow-sm hover:bg-green-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-green-700 focus:shadow-outline-green transition ease-in-out duration-150 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
             Salva
           </button>
         </span>
         <span class="mt-3 flex w-full rounded-md shadow-sm sm:mt-0 sm:w-auto">

           <button wire:click="closeModal()" type="button" class="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 bg-white text-base leading-6 font-medium text-gray-700 shadow-sm hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue transition ease-in-out duration-150 sm:text-sm sm:leading-5">
             Cancel
           </button>
         </span>
         </form>
       </div>

     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Livewire\Crud;
use App\Http\Livewire\Products;


/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/products', Products::class)->name('products.index');
Route::post('/products', Products::class)->name('products.index');
```

[image]

Comment: If you have errors, please shwo them in the question

Comment: 6 Days in the waiting? Did you post the error messages yet?

Comment: yes the message is the photo field is required like in the photo, but when push secondo time the save button all is ok

Comment: the problem was the time sorry, we need to save after image as been upload.

Comment: Hello, did you get the solution to this, I have similar problem